# Get all Alfresco tags with CMIS

Tags: alfresco, cmis, opencmis

I'm trying to get all tags (nodeRefs and names) from alfresco using CMIS.

The Alfresco version is 3.4.

Before googling a lot, I don't find any good query to do this? Any advice?

Comment: Do you want to get the Tags on a given Node, or do you want to get the Nodes which represent specific Tags?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gagravarr. I will try to clarify the question. I need to show all the tags on a Node (folder) recursively, because in my integration I have to make a form for uploading files and the user wants to add existing tags to the document in this moment.

Comment: Does it have to just be the tags used by that folder+children, or would the tags used on the Site containing the folder be OK? (Only Alfresco already maintains the list of the latter for you)

Comment: I need all the tags for all the Site (including the current folder). What's the best query to do this? It's possible to access via opencmis? Thanks a lot Gagravarr.

Comment: All the tags for a site is an easy query to make, just not one available via CMIS. You'll need to use the normal Alfresco APIs to get it. (I'll try to make an answer out of it later, if no-one beats me to it)

Comment: @Gagravarr You always get hung up in the comment section :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find a huge amount of detail written up on the [Alfresco wiki](https://wiki.alfresco.com/) on how the Tagging Service works, so if someone fancies taking this and updating the [wiki](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Tagging) that might be helpful!

There are three key parts to [tagging](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Tagging):

- Tag nodes themselves
- Tagged nodes
- Tag Scopes

Tag Nodes live under a special node `workspace://SpacesStore/tag:tag-root` which is in `/cm:categoryRoot/cm:taggable`. Tag Nodes are of type `cm:category` and the `cm:name` is the tag

Next, you'll want to apply a tag to a node. If it's a new tag, it needs creating in the tag root first. If this is the first tag on a node, add the `cm:taggable` aspect. Get the noderef of the tag node, then add that to the multi-valued `cm:taggable` property on the node. (The tagging service will do all of this for you if you call [addTag(NodeRef,String)](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/service/cmr/tagging/TaggingService.html#addTag%28org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef,%20java.lang.String%29)

Finally, various nodes up the primary parent hierarchy of the node you just tagged may be defined as a Tag Scope (eg the Site Node). With this, the nodes with the `cm:tagscope` aspect have the `cm:tagScopeSummary` property updated. `cm:tagScopeSummary` holds the list of tags used by the children of the node, along with the number of times the tag is used. This lets you work out what the most popular tags are for that bit of the tree, as well as working out what tags are used, and when a tag is no longer used by the tree. Again, the TaggingService updates all of that for you.

AFAIK, the various tag properties (`cm:taggable` and `cm:tagScopeSummary`) are not exposed via CMIS. You'd need to use one of the normal Alfresco APIs, either from the Public API, or something like `script/org/alfresco/collaboration/tagQuery.get` which will let you get the list of tags applied to a node. I'd suggest you ensure that the node you query from is a tag scope, so it's nice and quick. The Site is always a tag scope, so that's a good place to start.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you.

I think, correct me if I'm wrong, the tagging service addTag begins from 4.0 version of Liferay. isn't it?

So I can't make it works just with alfresco-opencmis-extension and chemistry-opencmis APIs? Could I use Web Services optionally?

Note: WARNING! I'm a newbie with Alfresco.

Comment: I don't know anything about liferay, sorry. I believe you'll need to make a non-CMIS REST api calls to get the data you want, calling straight to Alfresco.

Comment: Excuse I meant Alfresco 4.0 not Liferay. To many opened wars, sorry :-(

Comment: I wouldn't recommend trying it with WebServices. There's a very simple and easy to use REST api that does exactly what you need, use that! There's no point wasting huge amounts of time trying to hack something up badly with ws*, embrace the Alfresco way and go with the simple REST call!

Comment: Thank you very much @Gagravarr for your help. I really apreciated it. I will try to do the developement using REST API (REST API = Web Scripts, isn't it?). Could you help me with some examples?

Comment: The Alfresco wiki has lots of examples. Also, another good thing about simple RESTful APIs is that you can prototype most of it straight from your web browser!

Comment: Hi again, trying to use the Restful APi, I want to get the tags from a node with the service located on /alfresco/service/api/tagscopes/node/{store_type}/{store_id/{id}/tags but It always return a: 

404 Description: Requested resource is not available.
Message: 09170003 Script url /tags/workspace/SpacesStore/tag/nodes does not map to a Web Script.

What could be happening?

Thank you!

Comment: Check your URL, and make sure you're substituting in the right values for the parameters. If in doubt, find a bit of Alfresco that uses that API, and sniff the http traffic to see it in action